# Typecasting Array value in where query possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, casting, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently looking to implement a custom type with [ActiveRecord::Type::Value](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/value.rb) following [the enum implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L107), using Rails 5.0.0.beta1.1.

So far I have I got it working to cast everything from and to database correctly.

```
class BitFieldType < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
  def initialize(name, mapping, subtype)
    @name = name
    @mapping = mapping
    @subtype = subtype
  end

  def cast(value)
    [...]
  end

  def deserialize(value)
    [...]
  end

  def serialize(value)
    [...]
  end

  def assert_valid_value(value)
    [...]
  end

  protected

  attr_reader :name, :mapping, :subtype
end

class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  decorate_attribute_type(:my_attribute_name, :bit_field) do |subtype|
    BitFieldType.new(:my_attribute_name, [...], subtype)
  end
end
```

Only problem I have: I want to cast a array as a whole in `where()` calls, not each value.

Now, when I call for example:

```
SomeModel.where(my_attribute_name: [1, 2, 3])
```

... it passes each value (`1`, `2`, `3`) to my `serialize` method and then builds a query like

```
[...] where my_attribute_name IN (<serialized 1>, <serialized 2>, <serialized 3>)
```

I'd rather want to decide how that call turns out, so basically that the array `[1, 2, 3]` is passed to my `serialize` method, not each value of it. Then I could `serialize` it to an value which should simply be compared with `=`:

```
[...] where my_attribute_name = <serialized [1, 2, 3]>
```

Is this possible?

---

Edit: I more or less archived what I wanted by monkey patching [ActiveRecord::ActiveRecord::ArrayHandler](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/array_handler.rb)

```
diff --git a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/array_handler.rb b/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/array_handler.rb
index 95dbd6a..33077c1 100644
--- a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/array_handler.rb
+++ b/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder/array_handler.rb
@@ -6,6 +6,9 @@ module ActiveRecord
       end

       def call(attribute, value)
+        if attribute.relation.send(:type_caster).type_cast_where_array?(attribute.name)
+          value = Array.wrap(attribute.type_cast_for_database(value))
+        end
         values = value.map { |x| x.is_a?(Base) ? x.id : x }
         nils, values = values.partition(&:nil?)
```

This for now uses the protected method `:type_caster` and a new added method `.type_cast_where_array?`.

This new method has to be added to ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Map:

```
diff --git a/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/map.rb b/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/map.rb
index 3a367b3..b710081 100644
--- a/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/map.rb
+++ b/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/map.rb
@@ -11,6 +11,10 @@ module ActiveRecord
         type.serialize(value)
       end

+      def type_cast_where_array?(attr_name)
+        types.type_for_attribute(attr_name.to_s).type_cast_where_array?
+      end
+
       protected

       attr_reader :types
```

And to make that work with default types ActiveModel::Type::Value has to be patched, too:

```
diff --git a/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/value.rb b/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/value.rb
index 0d2d687..114f85d 100644
--- a/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/value.rb
+++ b/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/value.rb
@@ -50,6 +50,9 @@ module ActiveModel
         value.inspect
       end

+      def type_cast_where_array?
+      end
+
       # These predicates are not documented, as I need to look further into
       # their use, and see if they can be removed entirely.
       def binary? # :nodoc:
```

Now in my `BitFieldType` I can override that method to return true:

```
class BitFieldType < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
  def type_cast_where_array?
    true
  end
end
```

Last but not least ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Connection has to be patched with the new method too to make all tests pass.

```
diff --git a/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/connection.rb b/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/connection.rb
index 7ed8dcc..f5623b4 100644
--- a/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/connection.rb
+++ b/activerecord/lib/active_record/type_caster/connection.rb
@@ -12,6 +12,9 @@ module ActiveRecord
         connection.type_cast_from_column(column, value)
       end

+      def type_cast_where_array?(_attr_name)
+      end
+
       protected

       attr_reader :table_name
```

I know the method name might not be the best and using a protected method is bad, too, but that seems to be a way to type cast array where calls without too much code changes and all activerecord tests passing.

Any comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Arrays and hashes have a special meaning when passed to `where`. The exact same issue exists with the PG Array, JSON, and HStore types, as well as the `serialize` class macro.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a (relative small) monkey patch to my question to make it work for me without breaking anything else. What do you say about this approach? Should we discuss this somewhere else (mailing list?)? (I'd add tests, a guide and doc for this and/or refactor it if there's a chance for inclusion into Rails core.)

Comment: The short version is: I won't accept any patch that special cases this. The array/hash limitation on `where` is one of many examples of how `Relation` is fundamentally flawed as a query builder. I'm working to better decouple it from the rest of AR, so we can extract it to a gem, and then come up with something better. It's a very long process however.